# How to show bullets for subsections in the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, lists, enumerate, sections-paragraphs

I am writing my thesis with overleaf. I have used a `book` document class and I am proceeding in the enumeration of the chapters, sections and subsections. It looks fine from section to subsection where I want numbers both in the main file that in the table of contents.

The problem is that for subsubsection I would like to have a bullet (or any kind of pointing symbol) instead of numbers both in the main file and in the table of contents (in both cases indented, even if I think that in the toc it would be automatically indented). I do not know I to fix the problem. I tried with the * to delete the number, but then I do not know how to add the bullet and anyway in the text I would have still the number. Is there someone who could help me? Thanks a lot for your help.
The basic code could be this one

`\chapter{}
\section{}
\section{}
\subsection{}
\subsubsection{}`

The last part, that is the subsubsection I would like to have it without numbers both in the main file and in the toc and replacing numbers with bullet or any pointing symbol.

[image: At the end should look like this]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a small  complete code, that we can play with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{book} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % number subsubsections
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % put subsubsections in ToC
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\ensuremath{\clubsuit}} % no number, fancy glyph
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents}
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

Comment: super cool ;) thanks a lot, It really worked!!